# Conda Build and Finding Conflicts

Tags: python, conda, python-3.9, anaconda3, conda-build

I have a project that uses multiple requirements.  The are as follows:

```
dependencies = [
        "urllib3 >=1.25.10",
        "cachetools",
        "six",
        "lxml",
        "cryptography",
        "ipywidgets >=7",
        "widgetsnbextension >=3",
        "pandas >=1",
        "numpy >=1.16.2",
        "matplotlib",
        "keyring >=19",
        "lerc",
        "ujson >=3",
        "jupyterlab",
        "python-certifi-win32",
        'pywin32 >=223;platform_system=="Windows"',
        "pyshp >=2",
        "geomet",
        "requests",
        "requests-oauthlib",
        "requests_toolbelt",
        "requests_ntlm",
        'requests-negotiate-sspi;platform_system=="Windows"',
        'requests-kerberos;platform_system=="Windows"',
        'winkerberos;platform_system=="Windows"',
        "requests-gssapi",
    ]
```

When I use conda build with a meta.yaml file similar to what is shown in python 3.9 the build fails due to dependency issues.

What I am trying to figure out is what is causing the conflict?  Is there a simple output/print out that can just find the dependency issues?  The `conda build` command just spits out hundreds of lines of code stating every version of each package.

Comment: This seems like an atypical "package" to be building, particularly because of the `jupyterlab` and associated widgets packages. Is the package itself a Jupyter extension?

Comment: it contains a jupyter extension as well as other analysis tools

Comment: I would like to also note that it builds in py 3.6, 3.7, and 3.8 without issue using conda and builds in py 3.6-3.9 using python setup.py sdist.

Comment: I find Mamba to be better at identifying conflicts. Installing `boa` will provide the command `conda mambabuild`, which runs similar to `conda build` but uses `mamba` for the solving parts. Could give more specific feedback on what is failing. Also, instead of telling us the `meta.yaml` is similar, why not just share that? Then others could potentially replicate the error.

Comment: @merv I'll give mamba a try, thank you for the suggesting this.  I never heard of it!